# How to show Tapped Product Information in WishProductDetails.java

Tags: android, android-listview

**Like: we see in Cart Apps, when user selects some item(s) and at very last stage he/she wants to change quantity of an item, here we allow user to Tap on Item in List View to update quantity of an item, and once user tap on item in list view, we show him/her existing detail of an item, which has been tapped....in a same way i want to allow user to tap on item and want to show him existing detail for his item....Just want to show existing product information which has been tapped by user in WishProductDetails.java**

*Still i am able to show WishProductDetails.java but not able to show Tapped Item Details in Activity..*

I am using below code to show existing Item details in WishProductDetails.java which i have clicked in Cart Activity using List View Item row...

```
        HashMap<String, String> item = Constant.wishProducts.get(position);
        Log.d("CartAdapter", "onClick :: " + item);
        Intent myIntent = new Intent 
        (activity, WishProductDetails.class);
        Log.d("CartAdapter", "Intent :: " + myIntent);
        myIntent.putExtra("Item", item);
        activity.startActivity(myIntent);
```

Work related to add item into Cart and accept quantity of an item, all such works i am doing *WishProductDetails.java*

**Now i want whenever user do click on any of the ListView Item row, i need to show that particular item in WishProductDetails.java activity along with existing details.**

Comment: have a function delete in constant class. using the index you can delete an item from the list. to update the same in listview call notifyDataSetChanged() on your adapter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing that you are using an ImageButton to remove an item from cart, i have never worked on this kind of project but i am writing what i think, like:

```
 mImgBtnDelete = (ImageButton) vi
            .findViewById(R.id.mImgBtnDelete);
    mImgBtnDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Constant.wishproducts.remove(position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

**Edit #2**

```
Code to Update an Item using on ListView Item Row
```

I think in your Adapter class, you should add code something like below, to update quantity of an item while click on item row, but very frank i don't know how to open that particular item in WishProductDetail.java (where you are allowing user to enter quantity)

```
  public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View vi = convertView;
    if (convertView == null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cart, null);
        vi.setClickable(true);
        vi.setFocusable(true);
        vi.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


  @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            HashMap<String, String> prod = Constant.wishproducts.get(position);
        Intent mViewCartIntent = new Intent
                (activity,ProductInformationActivity.class);             
        mViewCartIntent.putExtra("product", prod);
        activity.startActivity(mViewCartIntent);           
        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks for great help, if possible so please also tell me how can i update product details using click on ListView item row,if i am allowing user to enter quantity of an item in WishProductDetails.java...

Comment: again thanks for support, but i want to know how can i update that particular item which i have clicked on Listview Item Row